# i am using rails 2.3.10 and i am using mysql database i try to create database for that time i am getting this error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

DEPRECATION WARNING: Rake tasks in vendor/plugins/restful-authentication/tasks are deprecated. Use lib/tasks instead. (called from /home/laxmimayee/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@catechumen/gems/rails-2.3.10/lib/tasks/rails.rb:10)

Comment: Why are you using rails 2.3.10?

Comment: hey dude just use latest stable version rails 4 why you using old one

Answer (score 0):

You need to add correct version of gem rake. I would suggest not to use rails 2. Support for rails 2 has been deprecated now. Try latest version of rails